# Como criar uma margem padrão no ckeditor?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

Comecei a utilizar CKEditor

E ao inicializar ele, vem da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E gostaria que ele viesse com uma margem padrão(Quero que fique semelhante a folha A4)

Como poderia fazer com que ele já viesse com um espaçamento?

Comment: Estou tentando formular uma resposta, porém vem a dúvida, a margem que você quer é interna(margem do conteudo do CK editor) ou externa? Fui claro em minha pergunta?

Comment: @SamuelDiogo margin interna

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O CKEditor permite que você passe estilos para dentro do editor, caso você esteja usando a versão 3 você deve usar o seguinte código javascript para adicionar estilos:

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'estilos-personalizados',
[
    { name : 'MarginA4', element : 'body', styles : { 'margin' : 'suamargin' } },
    { name : 'TamanhoDoTitulo' , element : 'h1', styles : { 'font-size' : 'tamanho da fonte' } },
]);
```

Isso cria uma "Folha de estilos", agora você precisa setar esta folha de estilos no seu editor, para isso você usa o seguinte código:

```
config.stylesSet = 'estilos-personalizados';
```

Onde `estilos-personalizados`representa o nome do estilo criado no `stylesSet.add`

Também há como colocar isso em arquivo externo conforme explicado neste site: [Developer Guides - Style](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles)

Na versão 4 do CKEditor há uma nova API que usa um objeto de estilo a `var style = new CKEDITOR.style( { element : 'body', attributes: { 'style' : 'margin: 10em' } } );` e este deve ser aplicado `editor.applyStyle( style );`

Mais informações sobre isso podem ser encontradas na documentação localizada em [Dev#styles](http://ckeditor.com/about/features#dev-styles)

Espero que isso responda sua pergunta.