# Como dividir o conteúdo em páginas no CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

Quero que o meu editor de texto (**CKEditor**) seja exibido como se fosse uma folha A4, que tenha margens para o texto e, quando este for aumentando, outras folhas do mesmo tamanho sejam adicionadas. Seria como um editor no estilo o Word.

Comment: Olá, Itamar. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Interessante sua pergunta, mas acho que é quase impossível ter alguma funcionalidade de paginação como essa pronta. E daria um bom trabalho fazer a distribuição do texto em páginas num navegador web por várias questões relacionadas à renderização de texto. Vamos ver se alguém conhece algo que lhe possa ajudar.

Comment: Espero que alguém saiba como resolver isso.

Comment: Se o que você quer são medidas "reais" acho que será meio difícil, os "navegadores" costumam trabalhar com `pixels` e a impressão com `mm` (ou `cm`), mesmo que você converta `px` para `mm` nunca será preciso (desculpe se entendi algo de errado). Ou você quer que o sistema do CKEditor simule as páginas e cada uma saia na sua própria página?

Comment: sim eu quero que o sistema do CKEditor simule as páginas e cada uma saia na sua própria página

Comment: Mas você precisa gerar conteúdo HTML? Porque HTML é corrido, não tem páginas.

Comment: @bfavaretto Sou eu, ou este OP "já era" ?

Comment: @Zuul Ele excluiu a conta.

Comment: @bfavaretto Respondo com a solução ou a pergunta vai acabar por ser "abatida" pelo sistema?

Comment: @Zuul Se tiver a solução, responda sim! Ela tem voto, está aberta. Só seria [excluída pelo sistema](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1558/74) daqui a um ano, e isso dependendo da quantidade de visualizações.

Comment: @bfavaretto Vou preparar um demo e a descrição dos passos a tomar, volto a este assunto mais logo com a resposta.

Comment: Olá user23583, a um tempo atras eu respondi uma pergunta parecida onde era perguntado como estilizar a área interna do editor do CKEditor http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50543/como-criar-uma-margem-padr%C3%A3o-no-ckeditor/51316#51316, acredito que usando a mesma API com um pouco de CSS você possa chegar no resultado esperado, além disso há um plugin chamado Pagebreak que tem como objetivo ajudar a definir seções para impressão como no word: http://ckeditor.com/addon/pagebreak